# How to overcome Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, inputmismatchexception, thread-exceptions

**Program:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaExercise1 {
    static int sum, num1, num2;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void add(){
        System.out.print("Enter first number to be added: ");
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number to be added: ");
        num2 = scan.nextInt();
        sum=num1+num2;
        System.out.println(num1+" + "+num2+" = "+sum);
    }
    static void sub(){
        System.out.print("Enter first number to be substracted: ");
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number to be substracted: ");
        num2 = scan.nextInt();
        sum=num1-num2;
        System.out.println(num1+" - "+num2+" = "+sum);
    }
    static void mul(){

            System.out.print("Enter first number to be multiplied: ");
            num1 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number to be multiplied: ");
            num2 = scan.nextInt();
            sum=num1*num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" x "+num2+" = "+sum);
    }
    static void div(){
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter first number to be divided: ");
            num1 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Entr second number to be divided: ");
            num2 = scan.nextInt();
            sum=num1/num2;
            System.out.println(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+sum);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nException occured...");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    static void printInstructions(){
        System.out.println("1. Addition\n2. Substraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ch;
        do{
            System.out.println("\nEnter your choice: (Choose 0 to print instructions)");
            ch = scan.nextInt();
            switch(ch){
                case 0: printInstructions();
                        break;
                case 1: add();
                        break;
                case 2: sub();
                        break;
                case 3: mul();
                    break;
                case 4: div();
                    break;
                case 5: break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice....");
            }
        }while(ch!=5);

    }
}
```

When I enter a number of greater digits is throws a thread exception (Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException)

> **Output:**
> Enter your choice: (Choose 0 to print instructions)
> 4
> Enter first number to be divided: 9999999999

> Exception occured...
> java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "9999999999"

> Enter your choice: (Choose 0 to print instructions)
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "9999999999"
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
> at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
> at JavaExercise1.main(JavaExercise1.java:52)

> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: To prevent exception, always call `hasNextInt()` before calling `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your input `9999999999` is bigger than the largest `int` in Java: `2147483647`.

Change your `scan.nextInt` to `scan.nextLong` and also the corresponding integers to `long` if you want to handle such large numbers.

Alternatively or additionally, use a `try-catch`  block to catch the exception and take appropriate action (like error message to user to try again).  This can be a part of normal user input checking.  Be very suspicious of user inputs because somebody might type `"Prithviraj is the greatest!"` instead of a number, for example.

And last but not least, welcome to the Stacks.